# How do I sum the digits of a number and then check if it exists in other number

Tags: c

How do I create a function that will take two integers, `num1`, `num2`, and return an integer and the function will check if the numeric value of the number `num2` is in the digits of the number `num1`.
example `num1 = 51749`, `num2 = 566`:
`num1` have `17`, `num2` sum is `17`

`int func(int num1, int num2)` this is the start of the function with no array.
I started this one but for some reason it's not working can you please explain me what is the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int func(int num1, int num2) {
    int sum = 0, sum2 = 0, ad = 0;
    int digit;

    while (num1 > 0) {
         digit = num1 % 10;
         sum = sum + digit;
         num1 = num1 / 10;
    }
    while (num2 > 0) {
         digit = num2 % 10;
         sum2 = sum2 + digit;
         num2 = num2 / 10;
    }
    while (ad < 10) {
        if (sum =! num2)
            printf("The number is correct");
        ad++;
    }
    printf("Different");
}

int main() {
    int a, b;
    printf("Type the first number ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Type the second number ");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    if (func(a, b) == 1)
        printf("Yes");
    if (func(a, b) == 0)
        printf("No");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "it's not working can you please explain me what is the problem" -- Why don't you try investigating this yourself? Have you tried running your code line by line in a debugger while monitoring the values of all variables, in order to determine in which line your program stops behaving as intended? If you did not try this, then you may want to read this: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/12149471) You may also want to read this: [How to debug small programs?](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Why do you have `while (ad < 0)` at all? But, your `if` seems wrong: `if(sum =! num2)` (a syntax error and wrong logic) --> `if (sum == sum2)`

Comment: Problem i don't know how to get the sum i get in num2 to check if the numbers in num1 do exist.

Comment: Unless your code sample is incomplete, I would think that compiling your code would have sent a warning about your function not having any code returning an integer value.  You might want to check that out.

Comment: I did `if` with `sum == sum2` it just gives me the number of the first sum and the second sum. It' doesn't show me the result i need.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which consists of a single code snippet containing a function `main` and all `#include` directives. This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in `if (sum =! num2)`: you probably mean this instead:

```
if (sum != num2)
```

In case you wonder why the bogus expression compiles at all, `sum =! num2` is parsed as `sum = !num2` which assigns `0` or `1` to `sum` if `num2` is zero or not.

Note also that your function does not test whether the sum of digits in `num2` exists inside `num1`. You must use a different method:

- compute `sum2`: the sum of digits in `num2`
- test if this number is present in `num1` either as a 1-digit or a 2-digit number (because `sum2` has either 1 or 2 digits).
- you may need to make a special case of (0, 0).

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int func(int num1, int num2) {
    int sum2 = 0;

    while (num2 > 0) {
         sum2 += num2 % 10;
         num2 /= 10;
    }
    if (sum2 == 0 && num1 == 0)
        return 1;   // special case for (0, 0)

    while (num1 > 0) {
         if (num1 % 10 == sum2)
             return 1;   // sum2 has 1 digit and is present
         if (num1 % 100 == sum2)
             return 1;   // sum2 has 2 digits and is present
         num1 /= 10;
    }
    return 0;  // sum2 is not present
}

int main() {
    int a = 0, b = 0;
    printf("Type the first number: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Type the second number: ");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    if (func(a, b)) {
        printf("Yes\nsum of digits in %d is present in %d\n", b, a);
    } else {
        printf("No\nsum of digits in %d is not present in %d\n", b, a);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes he probably copy paste it incorrectly .

Comment: A thousand gratitude's to you sir and all who help me to fix this code